# Footnote from intertext

Tags: footnotes, amsmath, align

I want to be able to send footnotes from `intertext`s I use within `align`. Is there an easy way to accomplish this (say using a package)?

For example,

```
I am a little teapot
\begin{align}
this &=spout
\intertext{Here is my handle,\footnote{(one hand on hip)}}
&=stout
\end{align}
these footnotes get eaten up.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Footnote within Intertext does not show (Align)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624506/footnote-within-intertext-does-not-show-align)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can issue a `\footnotemark` inside `\intertext` and outside `align` environment place the `\footnotetext` to get the footnotes inside `align`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
this &=spout\\
\intertext{Here is my handle\footnotemark,}
&=stout
\end{align}
\footnotetext{(one hand on hip)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't ensure that the mark and the footnote are on the same page.

Comment: @gen see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/624527/1090